# C# WebBrowser.DocumentText doesn't update after refresh or navigate again

Tags: c#, .net, refresh, webbrowser-control

I'll try to make it simple. When my program starts, a WebBrowser navigates to a URL. When it finishs loading, I use the event `webBrowser_DocumentCompleted` to test `if (webBrowser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)`. If true, I extract the html from the WebBrowser using `stringHtml = webBrowser.DocumentText;`, then do some HTML parsing to extract the information I need. (Basically, I need to retrieve some date/hour records in that page and show them). But the HTML of the URL changes when someone add another date/hour record. After adding other records, the user clicks a button in my program and it will do the work again: navigate to the URL, extract HTML, parse it and do stuff.

What is happenning: in my computer it works fine, but to some others the refresh/navigate again doesn't catch the new records. It brings the same HTML of the last time it was requested. I think WebBrowser has some kind of caching system. I've already tried:

- Do a `webBrowser.Refresh(WebBrowserRefreshOption.Completely)` before retrieving `DocumentText` again;
- `webBrowser.Document.OpenNew(true)` before the option above;
- `Navigate("about:blank")` + `Document.Write(String.Empty)` then navigate(myURL)
- `WebBrowser.Dispose()` then creating a new and then navigate
- I've Chrome as default browser and other people had IE, so I tried changing their default to Chrome too (though I think it doesn't matter)

The code looks something like this:

```
private void btnGetHTML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.OpenNew(true);
    webBrowser1.Refresh(WebBrowserRefreshOption.Completely);

    webBrowser1.Navigate(MyURL); // because Refresh doesn't fire DocumentCompleted event
}

private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
        stringHtml = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
        DoStuff();
    }
}

private void DoStuff()
{
    // For example, if I write stringHtml in a file just to check it, it will not be updated for some users
}
```

None of these solutions worked for others, but it still works just fine for me. Is this a caching issue? What should I do to get a updated version of the HTML?